# Sort yii2 gridview by column that's not in a model

Tags: sorting, gridview, yii2

I have Gridview and one column value I get via http request. Is there a way to sort the table by this column?

myTableModel.php

```
class myTableModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...,
    public function getExternalValue() {
        $client = new Client();

        return $client->createRequest()->setMethod('get')
        ->setUrl('http:://...')->setData(['id' => 1])->send()->content;
    }
}
```

myTableModelSearch.php

```
class myTableModelSearch extends myTableModel
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[...,'externalValue'], 'string'],
            [[..., 'externalValue'], 'safe']
        ];
    }
    public $externalValue;

    public function searchView($params) {
       $query = SomeTable::find();

       $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);

        $dataProvider->setSort(['attributes' => [
            'externalValue' => [
                'asc' => ['externalValue' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['externalValue' => SORT_DESC]
            ]
        ]]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate()))
            return $dataProvider;

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

view.php

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ... ,
        [
            'attribute' => 'externalValue',
            'value' => function($item) {
                return $item->externalValue;
            },
        ]
    ],
]);
```

I also tried to add value to view simply with `$item->getExternalValue()` (and without public property set), but it makes no difference - when trying to sort I get database exception error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'externalValue' in 'order clause'`. How could I trick gridview, to make it sort my table by `externalValue` column?

Comment: what database exception you get?

Comment: Nice to see a new way to write `php` class in `js` files **ಠ_ಠ** and where is the exception?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad, I updated the question. I'm using mysql database and the exception when trying to sort by column "externalValue" says, that column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `yii\data\ActiveDataProvider` which uses an instance of `ActiveQuery` to find its data.

Try using `yii\data\ArrayDataProvider`, or extend  `yii\data\ActiveDataProvider` to allow a second source for your `data`.

Additionally, you have to implement a sort function that can sort using your attribute.

see more [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#array-data-provider) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html)

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using yii\data\ArrayDataProvider, I will add working code later.